# Not changing Font or cell colors in Tablix rdlc based on IF - changing text instead

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, colors, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to change the cell or font colors in a column in an RDLC template expression based on if a date is earlier than current date.

```
=IIF(Fields!due_date.Value < Globals!ExecutionTime,"Red","Black")
```

the IF statement works but the field value gets changed to literal "Red", "Black", etc...  Which doesn't seem to be what other answers for similar questions I have seen on here are showing.  Please let me know what the super simple thing I am missing is.

Comment: It sounds like you are setting the expression for the Textbox's `Value` property instead of say, the Textbox's `BackgroundColor` property

Answer (score 0):

Well, the expression was for the value itself (thanks @Alan SchoField), I found out that you have to enter the expression directly into the 'Font Color" property box:

[image]